# std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0043f7c4.. error when using vectors and an input file

Tags: c++, exception

What i am trying to do is get user to enter a key code and if it matches to display the information on the data input file. I am getting this error  which i have no idea what for.

std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0043f7c4..

Below is my input file and my code

```
HEA,EMA,British Airways,030,025
HEA,EMA,Thomas Cook Airlines,020,040
HEA,DUB,British Airways,420,450
HEA,DUB,Thomas Cook Airlines,400,550
EMA,BAR,British Airways,120,140
EMA,BAR,Thomas Cook Airlines,100,150
ROM,EMA,British Airways, 120,125
ROM,EMA,Thomas Cook Airlines,150,090
ROM,BAR,British Airways,106,050
ROM,BAR,Thomas Cook Airlines,100,080
BAR,HEA,British Airways,125,090
BAR,HEA,Thomas Cook Airlines,100,120
DUB,EMA,Thomas Cook Airlines,450,380
DUB,EMA,Thomas Cook Airlines,420,450
```

below is my C++ code

```
#include <vector>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

//#include "TravelFunctions.h"




using namespace std;



vector<string>flightDetails;
vector<string>flightSearch;
string airportDepart;
string airportArrive;
bool errorArrive = false;
bool errorDepart = false;
string timeTaken;
int tax;
int cost;
bool needtoentercodes = false;
string entry;


 int main()
{
    // first i will read in the airport.txt data and store the information into a vector.
ifstream flightdata("flightinfo.txt");
    string flightnextline;
    if (!flightdata)
    {
         cout << "Cannot Open the file 'flightdata.txt'";
    }
    else
    {
         while (flightdata.good())
        {
            getline (flightdata, flightnextline);
            flightDetails.push_back(flightnextline);

         }
        flightdata.close();

    }







cout << " ___________________ " << endl;
cout << "|  Airport Key Code |" << endl;
cout << "|EMA = East Midlands|" << endl;
cout << "|HEA = Heathrow     |" << endl;
cout << "|BAR = Barcelona    |" << endl;
cout << "|ROM = ROME         |" << endl;
cout << "|DUB = DUBAI        |" << endl;
cout << "|                   |" << endl;
cout << "|___________________|" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;




 entry = "Please enter the ID code of the starting destination.\n";

while (needtoentercodes == false)
{

    cout<< entry;
    cout << "Use the key above to see which airports are available. \n"; 
    string userdepartid;
    cin>> userdepartid;
    bool k = false;

    //VALIDATING USER INPUT FOR DEPARTURE AIRPORT CODE - As mentioned above, this little section validates the starting departure id code.
    while (k==false){
        if ((userdepartid != "HEA") && (userdepartid != "EMA") && (userdepartid != "DUB") && (userdepartid != "BAR") && (userdepartid != "ROM"))
        {
            cout << "You have entered an incorrect departure code.\nPlease Try Again...\n";
            cin >> userdepartid;
        }
        else
        {
            k=true;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Please enter the code of the arrival destination.\n";
    string userarrivalid;
    cin >> userarrivalid;

    //VALIDATING USER INPUT FOR ARRIVAL AIRPORT CODE - This little section of code validates the arrival id airport code inputted in by the user.
    bool a = false;
        while (a==false){
        if ((userarrivalid != "HEA") && (userarrivalid != "EMA") && (userarrivalid != "ROM") && (userarrivalid != "DUB") && (userarrivalid != "BAR"))
        {
            cout << "You have entered an incorrect departure code.\nPlease Try Again...\n";
            cin >> userarrivalid;
        }
        else
        {
            a=true;
        }
    }

    int j = 1;
    bool resultsfound = false;
    cout << "\n";



    //RETURN THE RESULTS AND PUT THE RESULTS IN AN ARRAY - This little section places the searched results in a unique vector which then can be used later on in the program. 
    for (int i=0; i < flightDetails.size(); i++)
    {
        string tempflightdata = flightDetails[i];
        string departid = tempflightdata.substr(0,3);
        string arrivalid = tempflightdata.substr(4,3);
        if ((departid == userdepartid) && (arrivalid == userarrivalid))
        {
            cout << j << ":" << flightDetails[i] << "\n";
            flightSearch.push_back(flightDetails[i]);
            j++;
            needtoentercodes = false;
        }
        else
        {
            entry = "| Incorrect Entry. No direct connections! |\nPlease enter the ID code of the starting destination.\n";                 
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: also getting this error, really confused for a beginner c++ Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the old, old problem

```
    while (flightdata.good())
    {
        getline (flightdata, flightnextline);
        flightDetails.push_back(flightnextline);
    }
    flightdata.close();
```

should be

```
    while (getline (flightdata, flightnextline))
    {
        flightDetails.push_back(flightnextline);
    }
    flightdata.close();
```

Your while loop goes round one too many times because `flightdata` is still `good()` even *after* you've read the last line, and so you end up adding a blank line to your `flightDetails` vector. Later when you do `tempflightdata.substr(4,3);` on a blank line this causes the `out_of_range` error you see.

Caveat, I've only looked at the code, not debugged it.

Comment: Hmm i understand, i was wondering how to print the line which matches the airports?

Comment: @user2359244 That's a different question. Don't be so quick to ask for help. Think about it for a while and formulate a [sscce](http://sscce.org).